# How to check a post is sticky or not yet?

Tags: sticky-post

I want to check a post a post is sticky or not to do some function.
Thanks all for help ;)

Answer (score 3):

Use `is_sticky( $post_id )` to test if a post is a sticky post:

```
if ( is_sticky() )
    echo 'I am sticky!';


if ( is_sticky( 123 ) )
    echo 'The post with the ID 123 is sticky!';
```